# Delete found Contour from Mat - Find both Contour and Straight Line in an Image

Tags: opencv, image-processing, contour, opencv3.0

I am doing Image Processing and my goal is to find [Contours](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_contours/py_table_of_contents_contours/py_table_of_contents_contours.html)(Shapes) and then any straight lines.
For Contours, I am doing grayscale, threshing, inverting Image, Dilation, and Erosion as the pre-processing. Now after this pre-processing, all the lines become thick (due to Dilation and Erosion).

Now, after this, I am performing `findContour()` in OPENCV, which gives me all the contours, but now when I am trying to delete it from the preProcessed Mat, only a thin outer lines gets deleted, and hence I am not able to detect straight lines other than those in Shapes(Contours).

Can anyone help me how to find shapes and straight lines (other than in contours).

Comment: Please add some images to explain the problem(your output, expected output, the input image and any other image created during the runtime).

Comment: Some code to help illustrate your point would be nice.